# How to know if there are spaces in an input using php

Tags: php, html

I have a form to get information and when i type just spaces with no any other character it gets posted, How could i avoid inserting just spaces in the form?

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="textA"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="sent" value="Send">
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['sent']) && !empty($_POST['textA'])){
        $insert=new Insert();
        $insert->insertData($_POST['textA']);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) which will remove all leading and trailing spaces. If there are only spaces in the string then it will become an empty string and `empty()` will be true.

```
if(isset($_POST['sent']) && !empty(trim($_POST['textA']))){
```

You can also do things like `str_replace()` to replace spaces with and empty string or `preg_replace()` to do the same but this should do what you need.